# redirect not logged in users to specific page and redirect them back where they come from

Tags: login, woocommerce-offtopic, template-redirect

The problem is not the first redirection (already solved in other case here), the problem is the second redirection back.

No problem with the first redirection, when no logged in user come to page ID 10 (checkout page) he is directly redirect to custom login page but when he log in he is not redirect back to the checkout page, instead we can see before the login process in the url *xxx.com/myaccount/?redirect_to=xxx.com/checkout/*, he stay in the account page and dont go back automatically to the checkout page.

This is the code I used:

```
add_action('template_redirect','check_if_logged_in');
function check_if_logged_in()
{
    $pageid = 10; // checkout page
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid))
    {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            get_permalink($pagid),
            site_url('/myaccount/')
        );
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

I just need that the second back redirection to the checkout page works. This is what we need : 
No logged in user -> checkout page -> login page -> logged in -> checkout page

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `myaccount` is not the standard WordPress login page. It is a custom one? Is so, how do you handle the user log in?

Comment: No it is not the standart wordpress page. It is the standart woocommerce login page.

Comment: In that case you should ask to WooCommerce support team. [Third party plugins are off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as we may not know how it works.

Comment: I already did it. Of course you may not know how it works. Just hope someone knows.

Comment: Sorry  but "if someone knows" the answer, it doesn't make the question be on topic. Please, [read the help about what topics you can ask here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the login form on your custom login page. When using `wp_login_form()` you can include a redirect URL in the arguments ([Codex Entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form)).

The default URL is:

`( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

But you can override that:

```
if (get_query_var('redirect_to')) {
    $redirectURL = get_query_var('redirect_to');
    wp_login_form(array('redirect' => $redirectURL));
} else {
    wp_login_form();
}
```

Comment: Mike, read the comments. The login form the OP is using is the login from generated by WooCommerce.